# How can I update a column in SQL Server using a trigger

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, triggers

I am trying to create a trigger within SQL Server Management Studio that will increment a column value by 1 when a separate column has been updated within the same table.

The value for the column we want to update when the update script has been ran becomes NULL

My example is that I when I change the address of a customer, I want a column that goes up by 1 every time the address is changed i.e NoOfAddressess = 1, 2, 3 etc...

Here is the SQL code that I am writing

```
ALTER TRIGGER trg_customeraudit 
ON tblCustomer
AFTER UPDATE, DELETE, INSERT
AS
    INSERT INTO dbo.CustomerDetailsAudit 
    VALUES (CURRENT_USER, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 
            (SELECT CustomerID FROM inserted), 
            (SELECT CustomerAddress FROM deleted), 
            (SELECT CustomerAddress FROM inserted),
            (SELECT CustomerPostcode FROM deleted), 
            (SELECT CustomerPostcode FROM inserted), 
            (SELECT NumberOfChangedAddresses FROM dbo.CustomerDetailsAudit)  
           )

    IF ((SELECT CustomerAddress FROM inserted) = 
        (SELECT CustomerAddress FROM deleted) OR 
        (SELECT CustomerPostcode FROM deleted) = 
        (SELECT CustomerPostcode FROM inserted))
    BEGIN
        RAISERROR ('You must enter both a new postcode and address',16,10)
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
    END 
ELSE
BEGIN 
    PRINT 'Transaction successful'
    WHERE CustomerID = (SELECT CustomerID from inserted)
END

IF UPDATE (CustomerName)
BEGIN
    RAISERROR ('You cannot change the customer name', 16, 10)
    ROLLBACK
END
```

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Overflow. What's your question?

Comment: Your trigger has **MAJOR** flaw in that you seem to assume it'll be called **once per row** - that is not the case. The trigger will fire **once per statement**, so if your `INSERT` that causes this trigger to fire inserts 25 rows, you'll get the trigger fired **once** and the `Inserted` pseudo table will contain 25 rows. Which of those 25 rows will your code select from `Inserted`? It's non-deterministic, you'll get **one arbitrary row** and you will be **ignoring all other rows**. You need to rewrite your trigger to take this into account!

Comment: Hi, basically I’m just trying to create a trigger that updates a specific column when someone manually updates a column in the table. The problem we’re having is that the column comes up as NULL every when we have attempted to declare the value as 0

Comment: @marc_s , hi thanks for responsding, do you mean that I need to remove (SELECT NumberOfAddresses From dbo.CustomerDetailAudit) like from the Insert statement because it doesn’t know which value to insert?

Comment: A trigger `after update, delete, insert` will fire for statements other than `update`. (That will result in either `inserted` or `deleted` being empty and your subqueries would return NULLs.) The `else` clause with a floating `where` is mysterious. Presumably there are no other columns that you might want to update since you require _any_ update to change the values of both `CustomerAddress` and `CustomerPostcode`. `Update( ColumnName )` returns `true` if `ColumnName` is `set` in an `update` regardless of whether the value is actually being changed.

Comment: If your statement affects **multiple rows**, then statements like `SELECT CustomerID FROM inserted` are going to select **one, arbitrary** value from the 5, 10, or 25 entries in `inserted`, and ignore all the others. There's no guarantee which one will be chosen - so basically, all this code will work as long as nobody ever inserts, updates or deletes multiple rows at once. If that happens, this code will **NOT** do what you expect it to do! You need to completely rewrite your code

Comment: @marc_s I am only looking to update one row at a time, not multiple. So just were just editing one entry at a time

Comment: You're just asking for trouble once suddenly, somehow users or the program starts updating multiple rows....

Comment: If you are absolutely certain there will never be more than one row then _please_ add a check for the number of rows and use `RaIsError` or `Throw` to explicitly inform those who come along later that they have attempted to execute an unacceptable statement. (`if ( select Count(*) from inserted ) > 1 RaIsError( 'FooTable_Insert: No more than one row may be processed.', 25, 42 ) with log`)

Comment: hello @marc_s , I'm just getting into SQL and i'm just practising some basic tasks no real world scenarios. So i'm not looking to give error message, I'm just looking on how to increment the value by 1 every time another column is updated

Comment: as stated multiple times here, triggers are SET based.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the other things happening on this data triggers can be a very inefficient method of handling this, but here is one possible solution.

**1. Setup**

First create a table to use for testing.

```
create table test_table (
      MyPrimaryKey int primary key clustered not null identity(1, 1)
    , SomeColumn varchar(255) not null
    , SomeColumnCounter int null
);
go
```

Now, add a trigger to initialize the counter to 1. This could be handled by a default constraint or set at the application level but it can also be done with a trigger.

```
-- this trigger will set the counter to 1 when a record is first added
-- doesn't need to be a trigger, but since the question was on triggers
create trigger trg_test_table_insert
    on test_table
    after insert
as
    update tt
        set tt.SomeColumnCounter = 1
    from
        test_table as tt
    inner join
        Inserted as i
        on
            tt.MyPrimaryKey = i.MyPrimaryKey;
go
```

Now, add a trigger that will check for changes on the designated column and increment the counter if needed.

```
-- this trigger will increment the counter by 1 if 'SomeColumn' changed
-- doesn't handle nulls so will need to be modified depending on schema
create trigger trg_test_table_update
    on test_table
    after update
as
    update tt
        set tt.SomeColumnCounter = tt.SomeColumnCounter + 1
    from
        Inserted as i -- new version of the record
    inner join
        Deleted as d -- old version of the record
        on
            i.MyPrimaryKey = d.MyPrimaryKey
            and i.SomeColumn <> d.SomeColumn
    inner join
        test_table as tt
        on
            tt.MyPrimaryKey = i.MyPrimaryKey
go
```

**2. Testing**

Add some test data.

```
insert into test_table (SomeColumn)
values ('abc'), ('def');
go
```

Now we have:

```
MyPrimaryKey    SomeColumn  SomeColumnCounter
1               abc         1
2               def         1
```

Update without changing anything:

```
update tt
    set tt.SomeColumn = 'abc'
from
    test_table as tt
where
    tt.MyPrimaryKey = 1
```

We still have:

```
MyPrimaryKey    SomeColumn  SomeColumnCounter
1               abc         1
2               def         1
```

Update that actually changes something:

```
update tt
    set tt.SomeColumn = 'abbc'
from
    test_table as tt
where
    tt.MyPrimaryKey = 1
```

Now we have:

```
MyPrimaryKey    SomeColumn  SomeColumnCounter
1               abbc        2
2               def         1
```

Update that changes everything:

```
update tt
    set tt.SomeColumn = tt.SomeColumn + 'z'
from
    test_table as tt
```

Now we have:

```
MyPrimaryKey    SomeColumn  SomeColumnCounter
1               abbcz       3
2               defz        2
```